# Google Sign-In button's "onsuccess" callback doesn't seem to be triggering in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Sign-In component. The renderGoogleSignInButton function is successfully called, and the button is properly rendered, but after choosing a Google account from the typical pop-up, neither the "onsuccess" nor the "onfailure" callbacks trigger.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class GoogleSignIn extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.addEventListener('google-auth-loaded',
            this.renderGoogleSignInButton);
    }

    onSignIn = function (googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }

    renderGoogleSignInButton = () => {
        window.gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'theme': 'light',
            'longtitle': true,
            'onsuccess': this.onSignIn,
            'onfailure': this.onSignInFailure
        });
    }


    onSignInFailure = (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id='my-signin2'></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant piece of my site's head tag that imports the google library and triggers the event the component is listening for.

```
<!-- Google Sign-In -->
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="195820661004-2ecpj4s7j496bln8isgmt15qugctg367.apps.googleusercontent.com">

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleAuthLoaded" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function triggerGoogleAuthLoaded() {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('google-auth-loaded'));
    }
  </script>
  <!-- /Google Sign-In -->
```

Any idea why my console is empty after choosing a Google account?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394044/google-signin-button-with-reactjs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google+ signin button with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394044/google-signin-button-with-reactjs)